# Dynamic rows and columns in DataGrid and for each cell write from a WPF control

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, cell

I'm new to WPF and I'm trying to create a DataGrid with 4 columns defined "Ticket information", "Name", "Email" and "Zip Code". What I do is the following:

```
System.Data.DataTable table = new System.Data.DataTable();

    table.Columns.Add("Info Tickets");
    table.Columns.Add("Name");
    table.Columns.Add("Email");
    table.Columns.Add("ZipCode");
```

Later I intend to generate rows automatically depending on a number given by the user, I keep this amount in a variable and use it in a cycle to generate the rows in this way:

```
int quantity = (int)Application.Current.Resources["NumPeopleQuantity"];
    for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++)
    {
        // Create row
        System.Data.DataRow row = table.NewRow();

        row["Info Tickets"] = i + 1;
        row["Name"] = "";
        row["Email"] = "";
        row["ZipCode"] = "";

        // Insert the row
        table.Rows.Add(row);
    }
```

In the end I relate the table to the Data grid that I created as follows:

```
Grid1.ItemsSource = ((System.ComponentModel.IListSource)table).GetList();
```

This works correctly and the desired columns and rows are added to the DataGrid. So far everything perfect, I can write a name, email and zip code for each row from the keyboard of my computer, when the information has been filled correctly I have a button that retrieves all the content of the dataGrid and assigns it to a model to manipulate it In code, I do it as follows:

```
 System.Data.DataView data = (System.Data.DataView)Grid1.ItemsSource;


    var f = (PaymentViewModel)DataContext;

    string expresion;
    expresion = "\\w+([-+.']\\w+)*@\\w+([-.]\\w+)*\\.\\w+([-.]\\w+)*";

    for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
    {
        obj = new DataContactTicket
        {
            CustomerName = data.Table.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString(),
            CustomerEmail = data.Table.Rows[i]["Email"].ToString(),
            CustomerZip = data.Table.Rows[i]["ZipCode"].ToString()

        };
        if (obj.CustomerName == "" || obj.CustomerEmail == "" || obj.CustomerZip == "")
        {
            f.Mensaje = "Ticket information fields cannot be empty";
            return;
        }
        else
        {

            if (Regex.IsMatch(obj.CustomerEmail, expresion))
            {
                if (Regex.Replace(obj.CustomerEmail, expresion, String.Empty).Length == 0)
                {
                    names.Add(obj);
                }
                else
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                f.Mensaje = "Please validate the email format";
                return;
            }
        }
    }



    f.Grid1 = names;
```

I make the corresponding validations and assign them to a list in my ViewModel, everything is correct, the problem I have is that I need the user to type this information from an onScreenKeyboard and not from the keyboard of a computer for textboxes is easy , the reference looks like this:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TxtMail" Height="auto"  Width="500"  FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" TextChanged="TxtMail_TextChanged"
                    Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=onScreenKeyboard}"/>

 <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="114,-208,-114,208">
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-132,240,0,-240">
                    <TermControls:OnScreenKeyboard x:Name="onScreenKeyboard" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="4" />
                </StackPanel>
```

The idea is that for each cell of the dataGrid that the user selects, he can also write through the control in it, I have not found a way to do this. I hope you can help me, thank you very much.

Comment: I built a custom on screen keyboard recently. You need the control they're editing to have focus. Which means the keyboard must not be focussable. How i did the keyboard was by giving each key a string in tag. I handled the click routed event at the keyboard usercontrol level ( click bubbles ). I then had two ways of generating the input. One for the likes if tab and backspace. Another for single characters. Unfortunately i don't own the code so i don't have it to give you.

Comment: I already have a personalized control. Every time I press a letter on it, it draws it in the Textbox. The problem is that I want to do the same with each cell that the user selects but I can't find how to match them. With textbox it's easy, I just use ElementName.

Comment: @Angel Is the OnScreenKeyboard in the cell template? If so, bind *its* `Text` to TxtMail.Text.